# Find the data in either column A or column B, and will give you the third column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help me on the formula. Apologies for the format below as i am using my phone and i do not have excel on it. Let's say

```
Column A
1(cell a1)
2(cell a2)
3(cell a3)
Column B
4 (cell B1)
5 (cell b2)
6 (cell b3)
Column C
7 (cell c1)
8 (cell c2)
9 (cell c3)
```

Or Simply:

```
A1:C3
```

**1st scenario:**

If I enter 1 in cell D1, formula will give me 7. 

**2nd scenario:** 

If I enter 4 in cell D1, it will also give me 7.

I need only one formula that would give me this. I have tried to use index and match but i made it in two cells, one for each scenario. I would like if these two combine in one cell only. Thank you.

Comment: Are you counting the number of cells? Or is 1 in a1, 2 in a2, ... 9 in c3? And why is entering 1 or 4, give a result as 7 in D1? You have much to explain.

Comment: 1 is in a1, 2 is in a2, and follows. i would like by putting the data in cell a1 or b1, should give the data in cell c1.

Comment: In C1 write =If(OR(A1=1,B1=4),7,"") change "" for the value you want

Comment: Hi Yass, thanks a lot for this. But what if we will not focus on only one row. What i actually need is to find the data entered in cell D1 in column A, if it is in the list, it will get the data in column c, but if it is not in the list of column A, it will look in column B and will get the data in Column C

Comment: If D1=B2 for example do you want C2 or C1?

Comment: Hi yass thank you so much for helping me. We might not focus in one row. There is a long list in column A,B, and C. 1-9 is just an example. And whatever data i entered in (e.g. Cell D1, D2, or D3), it will look in either column a or b and the cells in column E would give me the data in column C. I am trying to use index and match formula but i can't perfect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long formula but you can drag it down for and value in column D it will give you the corresponding value in C same row of the value in column A or B that match D:

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$3,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$3,0)),"",INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(D1,$B$1:$B$3,0),1)),INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(D1,$A$1:$A$3,0),1))`

Replace $A$1:$A$3 with your first column
Replace $B$1:$B$3 with your second column
Replace $C$1:$C$3 with your third column
The Index is $C$1:$C$3 to find the result in column C only
The 0 in Match to have the exact Match
The 2 nested If to check if in column A there is a Match, else, the second If will check in column B for a Match
If in both columns A and B no Match it will return empty ""

Comment: Ohhhhh yass you're so great. You are really a genius. Thank you so much. I actually tried it and it is what i need. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

In **E1** enter:

```
=IF(OR(D1=A1,D1=B1),C1,"")
```

[image]

**EDIT#1**:

This will examine the complete columns:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$3,D1)+COUNTIF($B$1:$B$3,D1)>0,C1,"")
```

Comment: Hi Gary's Student, thanks a lot for this. But what if we will not focus on only one row. What i actually need is to find the data entered in cell D1 in column A, if it is in the list, it will get the data in column c, but if it is not in the list of column A, it will look in column B and will get the data in Column C

Comment: @Karen.A  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you. I am so blessed and you're helping me. Probably it is really my fault that i was not able to fully explain what i need. The 1-9 is just an example. What if it is not a number, countif might not be the formula. And it is not only the C1 should be the result, it will be any data in Column C based on the row. Is there a way i could send a picture? I'm trying to upload it but i couldn't post it. Apologies for the trouble

Comment: @Karen.A  Just edit your original question to indicate what you need.

Comment: Oh i do not have reputation yet to post images :( i'm just new here